# tensorflow data api with keras (passing tensors to keras model)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to train a pretrained keras model on new data. I came across tensorflow's dataset api and I am trying to use it with my old keras model. I understand that tf data api returns tensors, so the data api as well as model should be part of the same graph and the output of the data api should be connected as input to the model. Here is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf   
from data_pipeline import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import keras
from keras.engine import InputLayer

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
###################### to check visible devices ###############
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
###############################################################

_EPOCHS      = 10
_NUM_CLASSES = 2
_BATCH_SIZE  = 32


def training_pipeline():
  # #############
  # Load Dataset
  # #############
  training_set = ImageDataGenerator(directory="\\\\in-pdc-sem2\\training",
                                  horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rescale=True, normalize=True,
                                  color_jitter=True, batch_size=_BATCH_SIZE,
                                  num_cpus=8, epochs=60, output_patch_size=389, validation=False).dataset_pipeline()
  testing_set = ImageDataGenerator(directory="\\\\in-pdc-sem2\\training",
                                  horizontal_flip=False, vertical_flip=False, rescale=False, normalize=True,
                                  color_jitter=False, batch_size=_BATCH_SIZE,
                                  num_cpus=8, epochs=60, output_patch_size=389, validation=True).dataset_pipeline()

  print(training_set.output_types, training_set.output_shapes)

  iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(training_set.output_types, training_set.output_shapes)#((None, 389, 389, 3), (None)))

  train_initializer = iterator.make_initializer(training_set)
  validation_initializer = iterator.make_initializer(testing_set)

  img, labels = iterator.get_next()
  img = img.set_shape((None, 389, 389, 3))

  model = baseline_model(img, labels)  # keras model defined here
  model.summary()

  keras.backend.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for epoch in range(_EPOCHS):

      # #############
      # Train Model
      # #############
      keras.backend.get_session().run(train_initializer)
      model.fit(
          steps_per_epoch=1000000 // _BATCH_SIZE,
          epochs=1,
          # validation_steps=11970 // _BATCH_SIZE,
          callbacks=callbacks(),
          verbose = 1)

      keras.backend.get_session().run(validation_initializer)

      loss, acc, cross_entropy = model.evaluate(verbose=1, steps=11970 // 32)
      filepath = "./weights/ResNet_16_Best/weights-improvement-Run1-" + str(epoch) + "-" + str(loss) + ".hdf5"
      model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)


def baseline_model(input_tensor, labels):
    jsonFile = '\\\\in-pdc-sem2\\resnetV4_2Best.json'
    weightsFile = '\\\\in-pdc-sem1\\resnetV4_2BestWeightsOnly.hdf5'
    with open(jsonFile, "r") as file:
        jsonDef = file.read()
    from keras.models import model_from_json
    model_single = model_from_json(jsonDef)

    model_single.load_weights(weightsFile)
    model_single.layers[0] = InputLayer(input_tensor=input_tensor, input_shape=(389, 389, 3))
    model_single.compile(target_tensors=[labels], loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=[keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
    return model_single

def callbacks():
    tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./tensorboard', write_grads=False, write_images=False, histogram_freq=0)
    callbacks_list = [tensorboard]
    return callbacks_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    training_pipeline()
```

The "training set" returns image and label tuple, image is a tensor of shape (32, 389, 389, 3), its a batch of 32 images. I verified the shape in a separate script, it is correct. I am defining the input layer of the model using the tensor, and target tensors in the model.compile part.

This is what the model.summary output looks like:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 389, 389, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, 383, 383, 13) 1924        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)   (None, 383, 383, 13) 52          conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 383, 383, 13) 0           bn_conv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 191, 191, 13) 0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 4)  56          max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 4)  16          res2a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 4)  0           bn2a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 4)  148         activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 4)  16          res2a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 4)  0           bn2a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 8)  40          activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 191, 191, 8)  112         max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 8)  32          res2a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 191, 191, 8)  32          res2a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, 191, 191, 8)  0           bn2a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn2a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 8)  0           add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 8)  32          activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 8)  0           bn2b_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 4)  292         activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 4)  16          res2b_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 4)  0           bn2b_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 8)  40          activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_2 (Add)                     (None, 191, 191, 8)  0           res2b_branch2c[0][0]             
                                                                 activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2c_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 8)  32          add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 8)  0           bn2c_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2c_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 4)  292         activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2c_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 191, 191, 4)  16          res2c_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)       (None, 191, 191, 4)  0           bn2c_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2c_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 191, 191, 8)  40          activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (None, 191, 191, 8)  0           res2c_branch2c[0][0]             
                                                                 add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 96, 96, 8)    72          add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 96, 96, 8)    32          res3a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)       (None, 96, 96, 8)    0           bn3a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 96, 96, 8)    584         activation_9[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 96, 96, 8)    32          res3a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)      (None, 96, 96, 8)    0           bn3a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 96, 96, 16)   144         activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 96, 96, 16)   144         add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 96, 96, 16)   64          res3a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 96, 96, 16)   64          res3a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_4 (Add)                     (None, 96, 96, 16)   0           bn3a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn3a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)      (None, 96, 96, 16)   0           add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3b_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 96, 96, 16)   64          activation_11[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, 96, 96, 16)   0           bn3b_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3b_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 96, 96, 8)    1160        activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn3b_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 96, 96, 8)    32          res3b_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)      (None, 96, 96, 8)    0           bn3b_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res3b_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 96, 96, 16)   144         activation_13[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_5 (Add)                     (None, 96, 96, 16)   0           res3b_branch2c[0][0]             
                                                                 activation_11[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res4a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 48, 48, 16)   272         add_5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn4a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 48, 48, 16)   64          res4a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_14 (Activation)      (None, 48, 48, 16)   0           bn4a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res4a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 48, 48, 16)   2320        activation_14[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn4a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 48, 48, 16)   64          res4a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_15 (Activation)      (None, 48, 48, 16)   0           bn4a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res4a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 48, 48, 64)   1088        activation_15[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res4a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 48, 48, 64)   1088        add_5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn4a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 48, 48, 64)   256         res4a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn4a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 48, 48, 64)   256         res4a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_6 (Add)                     (None, 48, 48, 64)   0           bn4a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn4a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_16 (Activation)      (None, 48, 48, 64)   0           add_6[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn4b_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 48, 48, 64)   256         activation_16[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_17 (Activation)      (None, 48, 48, 64)   0           bn4b_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res4b_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 48, 48, 16)   9232        activation_17[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn4b_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 48, 48, 16)   64          res4b_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_18 (Activation)      (None, 48, 48, 16)   0           bn4b_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res4b_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 48, 48, 64)   1088        activation_18[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_7 (Add)                     (None, 48, 48, 64)   0           res4b_branch2c[0][0]             
                                                                 activation_16[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 24, 24, 32)   2080        add_7[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 24, 24, 32)   128         res5a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_19 (Activation)      (None, 24, 24, 32)   0           bn5a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 24, 24, 32)   9248        activation_19[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 24, 24, 32)   128         res5a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_20 (Activation)      (None, 24, 24, 32)   0           bn5a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 24, 24, 128)  4224        activation_20[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 24, 24, 128)  8320        add_7[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 24, 24, 128)  512         res5a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 24, 24, 128)  512         res5a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_8 (Add)                     (None, 24, 24, 128)  0           bn5a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn5a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_21 (Activation)      (None, 24, 24, 128)  0           add_8[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res6a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 12, 12, 64)   8256        activation_21[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn6a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 12, 12, 64)   256         res6a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_22 (Activation)      (None, 12, 12, 64)   0           bn6a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res6a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 12, 12, 64)   36928       activation_22[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn6a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 12, 12, 64)   256         res6a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_23 (Activation)      (None, 12, 12, 64)   0           bn6a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res6a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 12, 12, 512)  33280       activation_23[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res6a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, 12, 12, 512)  66048       activation_21[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn6a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 12, 12, 512)  2048        res6a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn6a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, 12, 12, 512)  2048        res6a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_9 (Add)                     (None, 12, 12, 512)  0           bn6a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn6a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_24 (Activation)      (None, 12, 12, 512)  0           add_9[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 512)          0           activation_24[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 512)          0           avg_pool[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
FC1 (Dense)                     (None, 1)            513         dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_25 (Activation)      (None, 1)            0           FC1[0][0]                        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 196,557
Trainable params: 192,867
Non-trainable params: 3,690
```

Everything looks correct. However When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ASista162282/Desktop/code/camleyon_17/train.py", line 114, in <module>
    training_pipeline()
  File "C:/Users/ASista162282/Desktop/code/camleyon_17/train.py", line 71, in training_pipeline
    verbose = 1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1705, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1188, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2478, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1111, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'input_1:0', which has shape '(?, 389, 389, 3)'
```

It doesn't make any sense. I even added the set_shape function before defining the model, and it still shows empty shape. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are replacing the input layer doesn't seem to connect the new layer correctly. Try replacing this:

`model_single.layers[0] = InputLayer(input_tensor=input_tensor, input_shape=(389, 389, 3))`

with this:

`from keras.models import Model
model_single.layers.pop(0)
new_input = InputLayer(input_tensor=input_tensor, input_shape=(389, 389, 3))
new_output = model_single(new_input)
model_single = Model(new_input, new_output)`

Comment: I did that, I am getting the following error: ValueError: Layer resnetV4.2 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.topology.InputLayer'>

Comment: I added another line to my answer (see line `model_single.layers.pop(0)`) to remove the old input layer that was missing in my original post. This might do it now

Comment: That didnt work either. But for some reason using keras.layers.Input worked, rather than InputLayer. No idea why.